# npm ERR! missing script: setup

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

How can I resolve this error(When i use npm run setup)?

> `npm ERR! missing script: setup`

This is my scripts in my package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ionic serve",
    "build": "ionic build",
    "build:prod": "NODE_ENV=production ionic build --prod",
    "build:test": "NODE_ENV=testing ionic build",
    "dev:android": "ionic cordova run android --livereload",
    "dev:ios": "ionic cordova run ios",
    "prod:android": "NODE_ENV=production ionic cordova run android --prod",
    "prod:ios": "NODE_ENV=production ionic cordova run ios --prod",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=testing gulp && jest --verbose",
    "test:ci": "NODE_ENV=testing gulp && jest -ci --runInBand --verbose",
    "test:watch": "NODE_ENV=testing gulp watch & jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "NODE_ENV=testing gulp && jest --coverage",
    "lint": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 ng lint",
    "ionic:serve:before": "gulp",
    "ionic:serve": "./scripts/serve.sh",
    "ionic:build:before": "gulp"
  }
```

- My nvm version is: 0.38.0
- My npm version is: 6.7.0
- My node version is: v11.15.0
- My system is macBook

---

**Edit:** This is the [setup documentaion](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2#Updating_plugins) that I'm following

Comment: It indicates that there is no script named `setup` in your `package.json` file

Comment: Who's calling the script `setup`? If you really need it, just add it.

Comment: @omidh, How can I do?

Comment: Why do you need this script? Who's calling it and why? What's the expected behavior of this script? You could add an empty script like `"setup": "echo setup"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script named `setup` does not exist in *package.json* for the latest release of `moodleapp` ([v3.9.5](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodleapp/releases/tag/v3.9.5)).

However, version [v3.9.4](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodleapp/releases/tag/v3.9.4) of `moodleapp` does include the following `setup` script in *package.json*:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "setup": "npm install && npx cordova prepare && npx gulp".
  ...
},
...
```

Perhaps the [Setup the environment](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2#Setup_the_environment) section of the docs is outdated.

Use version `3.9.4` of `moodleapp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your script is not `serve` but `ionic:serve`; So try running `npm run ionic:serve`